# Create web messenger service

Tags: xmpp

Am wondering if anyone can suggest the right technology required to create a web-messenger service similar to Meebo i.e. it should be able to connect to various services like Facebook, Gtalk etc. I know they are all Jabber compatible. Am wondering if anyone can suggest a technology that is required to connect to these servers? Also, is there an API or a service available instead of re-writing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

[What about Google AppEngine?](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html)

> With the introduction of the XMPP
>   service to App Engine, it's now
>   possible to write an App Engine app
>   that communicates with users - or even
>   other applications - over XMPP,
>   otherwise known as Jabber or Google
>   Talk.